# How to return a unique list that contains a string?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return a unique list that contains a string:

Example:
Criteria - contains "Banana"

```
Original List        Desired List
1Banana              1Banana
1Banana              2Banana
1Orange              4Banana
1Apple
2Banana
2Banana
2Apple
2Apple
3Orange
3Apple
4Orange
4Banana
4Banana
5Apple
```

Comment: This is a well written question, but is it on topic for stack overflow, or does it belong over in Super User?  I hesitate to flag because I could be wrong and don't want to discourage a brand new user who is obviously on the right track.

Comment: @BarryGackle Actually it is on topic here if the OP is seeking formula/vba help.  But they have not listed anything they have tried, nor what they want to use which makes it a poorly written question

Comment: The author of this question provided no programming attempt at solving the problem and is asking us to write code for them.  I'm flagging to close this question because it does not contain a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @chancea Thanks!  It was Excel formulas specifically that I was unsure about.  Question itself seemed reasonable to me since the end result that is desired is clear, and it seems possible that Excel would offer a single function that does this, in which case pointing that out would be appropriate.  Agreed that asking us to throw a whole VBA script at the problem would be too much.

Comment: @BarryGackle Yeah if you want further reading on the communities decision about excel formulas you can see [This meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic)

Comment: Oh sorry i was looking for a excel formula, not vba, is there somewhere else i should post this?

Comment: @drv82 No this is fine to post questions regarding Excel formulas.  But you _did not specify_ that in your question.  Nor did you tag your question with [tag:Excel-Formula].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming original list in A2:A15 then with header in B1 use this array formula in B2

> =IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$15,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",A$2:A$15))*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A$2:A$15)=0),0)),"")

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copy down column. When valid entries are exhausted you get blanks. This is not case-sensitive